# Could get right file size using du

Tags: linux, filesize, du

I see that my bucket size on the aws s3 storage is 13.2GiB and it has 1570 files:

```
$ aws s3 ls --summarize --human-readable s3://mybucket/ | grep -E "(Total\sObjects|Total\sSize)"
Total Objects: 1570
   Total Size: 13.2 GiB
```

When I downloaded this bucket here is what I see:

```
$du -sh ./test
14G
$wc -l ./test
1570
$ du -sb ./test
14204477032
$ du -sb ./test | awk '{ \
            split( "B KB MB GB" , v ); \
            s=1; \
            while( $1>=1024 ) { \
                $1/=1024; s++ \
            } \
            printf "%.1f%s", $1, v[s] \
        }'
13.2GB
```

How to achieve the same result using standard Linux functions?

Comment: "standard Linux functions" - doesn't awk count? Or do you need du to round to do the rounding to 1 decimal place? There's also [numfmt](http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/numfmt.html) if that counts as more standard.

Comment: Actually no, numfmt doesn't support forcing decimal places (annoyingly it rejects `--format %.1f` :-( )  and it gives 14G for your example.

Comment: The manpage of du says:
‘-h’
‘--human-readable’
Append a size letter to each size, such as ‘M’ for mebibytes. Powers of 1024 are used, not 1000; ‘M’ stands for 1,048,576 bytes. This option is equivalent to --block-size=human-readable. Use the --si option if you prefer powers of 1000.

Comment: @LupusE, I read it, but the problem that du round size a bit strangely, 13.2 -> 14GB. I need to get a file size with some precision.

Comment: Your command should be 'du -sbh <file>' ... You are comparing 'du -sh' (sum from 'usage on disk' in human-readable [1024]) and 'du -sb (plus awk)' (sum from 'size of file'). The 'usage of disk' will be higher when the size of each file isn't the same or a multiple of the filesystems blocksize.

Answer (score 1):

`du` is originally for finding out how much space a file occupies on the storage medium (disk).  That's the main reason why it rather rounds up than down.  A started allocated block is always "used" completely, even if just two bytes of it are in use.

Your case rather seems to aim at counting the bytes in the files, regardless of the storage space they occupy.  For this, `du` has the option `--apparent-size`.  Rather than disk usage, it then displays the file's sizes.  Combined with `--block-size=1` this is simpler spelled as `-b`.

Next thing is that you want to convert a large number like `14204477032` into a neat version like `13.2GB`.  You also state in a comment that `14G` (as `-h` would produce) isn't precise enough for your taste, and you *also* provide an `awk` script which does exactly this conversion so that you already have a working solution.

I'm not aware of any standard Unix tool other than `awk` or even more complex things like `perl` or `python` which would do this in a much easier fashion.  There are other people looking for a solution for this, and yours is among the best ones.

SO my advice is just this:  Stick with your solution.  The only improvement I'd propose would be to use bit-shifting (`>> 10`) instead of division (`/ 1024`) but that's rather a matter of taste.